# number of ordered partitions for 0 to n^2

Tags: combinatorics

Using from o to $n$ numbers from $1$ to $n$ what is the number of ordered partitions from o to $n^2$?  From $n=0$ to $4$ the sequence begins $1,2,9,64,341.$

Comment: How do you get $9$ for $2$? I find the empty partition, two partitions of length $1$ and four of length $2$ for a total of $7$.  Since you don't limit the total, it is better to talk of sequences than partitions.

Comment: Indeed.  Would it not be simply $f(n)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n n^i$?  See [oeis/A031973](http://oeis.org/A031973).

Comment: Ordered partitions are also called [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).  They are relatively easy to count in comparison with (unordered) partitions.  However your Question doesn't quite identify what you want.  Are you expressing some number $N$ as a sum of (ordered) summands $0$ to $n$?  When zero is allowed as a summand we call this a *weak composition*.